# Empty result when query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a report with the brands that have no sales for a specific period. Here's what I have tried until now but I get an empty column `Brand_Name`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Brands$.BRAND_NAME
FROM
    Brands$
INNER JOIN 
    Products$ ON Brands$.BRAND_ID = Products$.BRAND_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    InvDetails$ ON Products$.PRODUCT_ID = InvDetails$.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN 
    Invoices$ ON Invoices$.INVOICE_ID = InvDetails$.INVOICE_ID
WHERE 
    InvDetails$.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL 
    AND (Invoices$.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN '2013-10-22 23:41:49.143' 
                                    AND '2013-11-22 17:54:03.437')
```

Comment: update a proper data sample and the expetced  result

Comment: comment out where clauses to see which one causes this, do the same with joins if no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Brands$.BRAND_NAME
FROM Brands$
INNER JOIN Products$ ON Brands$.BRAND_ID = Products$.BRAND_ID
INNER JOIN InvDetails$ ON Products$.PRODUCT_ID = InvDetails$.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN Invoices$ ON Invoices$.INVOICE_ID = InvDetails$.INVOICE_ID
WHERE Invoices$.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN '2013-10-22 23:41:49.143' AND '2013-11-22 17:54:03.437'
```

you get the products that **have sales** for this specific period.
So by using `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT Brands$.BRAND_NAME
FROM Brands$
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT Brands$.BRAND_NAME
FROM Brands$
INNER JOIN Products$ ON Brands$.BRAND_ID = Products$.BRAND_ID
INNER JOIN InvDetails$ ON Products$.PRODUCT_ID = InvDetails$.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN Invoices$ ON Invoices$.INVOICE_ID = InvDetails$.INVOICE_ID
WHERE Invoices$.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN '2013-10-22 23:41:49.143' AND '2013-11-22
```

you get all the products that **do not have sales** for this specific period.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the condition for left join table in ON clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT Brands$.BRAND_NAME
FROM Brands$
INNER JOIN Products$ ON Brands$.BRAND_ID=Products$.BRAND_ID
LEFT JOIN InvDetails$ ON Products$.PRODUCT_ID=InvDetails$.PRODUCT_ID 
        AND InvDetails$.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL
INNER JOIN Invoices$ ON Invoices$.INVOICE_ID=InvDetails$.INVOICE_ID
   AND (Invoices$.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN '2013-10-22 23:41:49.143' AND '2013-11-22 17:54:03.437')
```

If you use where with column related  to left join table then work as an inner join

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need two `LEFT JOIN`s and to move the condition on invoices to the `ON` clause;

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.BRAND_NAME
    FROM Brands$ b JOIN
         Products$ p
         ON b.BRAND_ID = p.BRAND_ID LEFT JOIN
         InvDetails$ id
         ON p.PRODUCT_ID = id.PRODUCT_ID LEFT JOIN
         Invoices$ i
         ON i.INVOICE_ID = id.INVOICE_ID AND
            i.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN '2013-10-22 23:41:49.143' AND '2013-11-22 17:54:03.437'
WHERE id.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL;
```

Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to find records from one table with no corresponding records in another table(s), [`NOT EXISTS` will perform better on SQL Server than `LEFT JOIN\IS NULL`](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/), in addition, I find it conveys intent much more clearly, e.g.

```
SELECT  b.BRAND_NAME
FROM    Brands$ AS b
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Products$ AS p
                    INNER JOIN InvDetails$ AS id
                        ON id.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID
                    INNER JOIN Invoices$ AS i
                        ON i.INVOICE_ID = id.INVOICE_ID
            WHERE   i.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN '2013-10-22 23:41:49.143' AND '2013-11-22 17:54:03.437'
            WHERE   p.BRAND_ID = b.BRAND_ID
        );
```

In some cases there will be no performance difference between the two, but in this case I would definitely expect `NOT EXISTS` to perform better, as at the very least you have removed the need to remove duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

I am using NOT EXISTS to exclude any brands with invoices for the given period

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.BRAND_NAME
FROM Brands$ b
INNER JOIN Products$ p ON b.BRAND_ID=p.BRAND_ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM Invoices$ i
                 JOIN InvDetails$ id ON i.INVOICE_ID = id.INVOICE_ID
                 WHERE i.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN '2013-10-22 23:41:49.143' AND '2013-11-22 17:54:03.437'
                   AND id.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find brands with invoice and exclude.

```
SELECT B.BRAND_NAME FROM Brands$ B
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Brands$.BRAND_NAME
        FROM Brands$
        INNER JOIN Products$ ON Brands$.BRAND_ID=Products$.BRAND_ID
        JOIN InvDetails$ ON Products$.PRODUCT_ID=InvDetails$.PRODUCT_ID
        JOIN Invoices$ ON Invoices$.INVOICE_ID=InvDetails$.INVOICE_ID
        WHERE InvDetails$.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL  AND (Invoices$.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN '2013-10-22 23:41:49.143' AND '2013-11-22 17:54:03.437')
    GROUP BY Brands$.BRAND_NAME ) T ON B.BRAND_NAME  = T.BRAND_NAME
WHERE T.BRAND_NAME IS NULL
```

Instead of brand name a numeric id will be must faster to compare.